# Java Hibernate Hierachy Different JoinColumn in Child class Column 'C01' specified twice

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have several Entitys in my models but some of them share a same property namely `Student`. I have created a abstract class like this.

```
@javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass
public abstract class StudentImpl 
{
   private Student student;
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)@JoinColumn(name="c01")    
   public Student getStudent(){return student;}
   @Override
   public void setStudent(final Student student){this.student=student;return;}
}
```

This is working like a charm. See that the 95% of them have mapped to `C01` column in my MySQL table.

I have use this abstract class extending each of my Models with share the same property.

```
public class Teammate extends StudentImpl
```

The problem arise in some classes the Student property is mapped to a different column name in their table

Example

```
create table myTable 
(
   c02 int(11) NOT NULL, //student entity is mapped to c02 column instead of c01
)
```

As you can see they mismatch c01 and c02 and their column c01 column is mapped to a simple `String` instead of a Student.

I have try

```
@javax.persistence.AttributeOverride(name="student",column=@Column(name="c02"))
```

Wishing Hibernate could understand student property is mapped to column c02 in this Entity.

```
@javax.persistence.AttributeOverride(name="student",column=@Column(name="c02"))
public class AnotherClass extends StudentImpl
{
    private String c01;
    private String getC01(){return this.c01;} //Column c01 is mapped to a String 
}
```

But seems not working because it Throws

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'C01' specified twice.
```

This problem arise when I try to insert a new AnotherClass registry.

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to accomplish it?

### Solved

I have found the solution thanks to @ddalton. I used this and this is working:

```
@javax.persistence.AssociationOverride(name="student",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c02"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AssociationOverride annotation to accomplish this:

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/AssociationOverrides

Comment: I have follow your link your code `@javax.persistence.AssociationOverrides({@javax.persistence.AssociationOverride(name="student",joinColumns=@JoinColumn("c02"))})` but it netbeans it throws a compilation error. `symbol:   method value()
  location: @interface JoinColumn` what i am doing wrong.